# Extended EDT does not compare dates

Tags: x++, axapta

There are two EDTs which extend from Transdate. And they both have same values.

The purpose is to compare two dates and then execute the remaining loop. But it is not executing the loop.

The problem is not about comparison.  Example:

```
x = 5/1/2012; // showing error if we give like this

y = 5\1\2012;

z = systemdateget(); //but taking the same value as x

if(x == z)
{
   .........
}
if(y == z)
{
  ..............
}
```

I tested the above job and it is just for example and understanding, but my main problem is about date compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [date constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa865135.aspx) should be written as 1\5\2012 in day, month, year order.

Remember: AX is made in Denmark.